# Unable to delete a message sent via Incoming Webhooks

Tags: slack, slack-api

I am using Slack Incoming Webhooks requests to post messages to a Slack channel from an app. I love it since I can send messages directly from shell scripts.

However going further I stumble into the problem that I seem to be unable to delete messages.

The app has two access tokens:

- An OAuth access token `xoxp-012345678901-012345678901-012345678901-0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef` (*this is a fictitious token but the length is the same as the actual token*).
- Bot User OAuth access token `xoxb-012345678901-012345678901-0123456789abcdef01234567`.

Using the `xoxp-` OAuth access token I can retrieve channel history.

```
curl "https://slack.com/api/channels.history?token=xoxp-012345678901-012345678901-012345678901-0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef&channel=CABCDABCD&count=20&pretty=1"
```

With the `xoxb-` token the `channels.history` request fails with

```
{
    "ok": false,
    "error": "not_in_channel"
}
```

In chat history I have a message that I would like to delete. The message was posted using Incoming Webhooks associated with the App.

```
{
    "type": "message",
    "subtype": "bot_message",
    "text": ":heavy_check_mark:",
    "ts": "1580968882.000800",
    "bot_id": "BABCDABCD",
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "section",
            "block_id": "5Ov",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": "text of the message to delete",
                "verbatim": false
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

However neither token works with `chat.delete`. Both

```
curl "https://slack.com/api/chat.delete?token=xoxb-012345678901-012345678901-0123456789abcdef01234567&channel=CABCDABCD&ts=1580968882.000800&pretty=1"
```

and

```
curl "https://slack.com/api/chat.delete?token=xoxp-012345678901-012345678901-012345678901-0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef&channel=CABCDABCD&ts=1580968882.000800&pretty=1"
```

fail with

```
{
    "ok": false,
    "error": "cant_delete_message"
}
```

**And the question is:** Is there a way to delete a message posted by an app via Incoming Webhooks requests?

**PS.** Both `chat:write:bot` and `chat:write:user` permissions are granted.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but the token owner needs to be admin in order to have the right to delete message of other users / apps.

To clarify: This has nothing to do with OAuth scopes, but with the Slack role of the user who owns the token.